# How can I change slides with scroll event infinitely. Have it working with set interval function, but how to scroll function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this https://codepen.io/mikun/pen/YWgqEX and. Instead of it infinity changing slides, I want it to wait for the scroll event.

I have added this to it but it isn't working the right way.

```
$('.slide-nav').on('click', function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
// get current slide
var current = $('.flex--active').data('slide'),
// get button data-slide
next = $(this).data('slide');

 $('.slide-nav').removeClass('active');
 $(this).addClass('active');

  if (current === next) {
    return false;
      } else {
   $('.slider__wrapper').find('.flex__container[data-slide=' + next + 
   ']').addClass('flex--preStart');
   $('.flex--active').addClass('animate--end');
   setTimeout(function() {
   $('.flex--preStart').removeClass('animate--start flex-- 
   preStart').addClass('flex--active');
   $('.animate--end').addClass('animate-- 
  start').removeClass('animate- 
 -end flex--active');
  }, 800);
 }
});

window.onscroll = function Onscrollfunction() {
  if (current === next) {
    return false;
    } else {
    $('.slider__wrapper').find('.flex__container[data-slide=' + next 
    + ']').addClass('flex--preStart');
   $('.flex--active').addClass('animate--end');
  } 
 }
```

Comment: Are there line breaks in your actual code like that? If so that could well be your problem as is a syntax error when placed within a `'` delimited string.

Comment: I can clean it up but i was really focusing on the function itself not working as i would like. If you check the link, the slides will change with that js but I want it to scroll when the user scrolls